# Got my first serial downvote

Tags: support

23 downvotes on different questions in a 1 minute period (around 15:30 GMT).

I suppose most active members will have suffered this at some point, but it's my first and it's surprisingly annoying. I trust the serial downvote detector will be along at some point to reverse this?

Comment: Presumably this is a easy case for the serial vote reversal.

Comment: So one guy starts downvoting every answer? Why would anyone do that?

Comment: I got downvoted 6 times today

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the votes should be reversed within 24 hours. If they're not, then it's time to let a moderator know, on meta or chat or by a custom flag on one of the affected posts.

For further information see [this post on meta.SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212332/what-should-you-do-if-youre-serial-downvoted-it-isnt-automatically-reversed).

Comment: Yes, all the downvotes were reversed this morning :-)